SqlTransaction is disposed unexpectedly when SET IDENTITY_INSERT fails
I am facing an issue with SqlTransaction, where the transaction object is rolledback and disposed unexpectedly. This seems to specifically occur when SET IDENTITY_INSERT is called on an unknown table. I'm not seeing same issue with other types of sql errors. Here's a minimal example:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

var connStr = @"server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;integrated security=True;";
using var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
using var tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    using var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.Transaction = tran;
    cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT badtable ON"; // transaction is disposed with this
    // cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM badtable";  // transaction is NOT disposed with this
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Transaction disposed: " + (tran.Connection == null).ToString());
    throw;
}

I'm curious why the transaction is disposed here.

What do you mean with transaction is disposed Do you mean you have a rollback? The code above never commits the transaction so it is always rolled back when you exit the function and the transaction is disposed

@Steve when it enters the catch block, the transaction has already been rolledback, and tran.Connection is null.

Weird, I can confirm this happens also here

My bad.... same error.

Transactions can often be automatically rolled back in case of error. If you have an error with an open transaction, you should assume the transaction is doomed and roll it back. Always use SET XACT_ABORT ON as this will force that to be the case always.

SELECT 1 FROM bedtable
fails with

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 28 Invalid object name 'bedtable'.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT bedtable ON
fails with

Msg 1088, Level 16, State 11, Line 20 Cannot find the object
"bedtable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

So they are different errors, and it turns out the effect of the errors is different.  Error 208 is a failure in deferred name resolution, and it's aborts the scope, but not the whole batch and doesn't rollback the current transaction.
Error 1088 aborts the whole batch and rolls back the transaction.
And yes, this make little obvious sense.  But Error handling in T-SQL is notoriously complex.  See, eg:
https://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#scope-abortion
